# How to get object's values from object in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting one column from Member table. Now I want to get the value from this column. But when I try to get the value I am getting an exception as :

```
 <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in
<b>C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\MLMapi\PurchaseProduct.php</b> on line
<b>54</b>
<br />
```

Code:

```
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select Member.sales_hold_fund from Member where member_id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($member_id));
    $member = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $fund = $member-> sales_hold_fund;// line54

        $sales_hold_fund = $fund + $amount;
```

I want to get the sales_hold_fund value from database and add the amount value to the sales_hold_fund.

member value :

```
 "Member": {
    "sales_hold_fund": "1000"
  }
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Comment: `print_r($member);` check this first.

Comment: I get the value of member I can see the sales hold fund. @devpro

Comment: are you sales_hold_fund filed in database ? plz  `print_r($member)`

Comment: please check edited question. @hasanmovahed

Comment: than you must got the solution, member either array or object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 $fund = $member['sales_hold_fund'];
```

Comment: yes get it..thank you.. @safin chacko